# PyTorch svd() reconstruction fails

Tags: python, pytorch

This has been solved in the comments.

---

The following tests both return `False` when nn.DataPrallel is being used:

(1) Using [torch.svd()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.svd.html)

```
u_, s_, v_ = torch.svd(x)
is_same = torch.allclose(x, torch.matmul(torch.matmul(u_, torch.diag_embed(s_)), v_.transpose(-2, -1)))
```

(2) Using [torch.linalg.svd()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/linalg.html#torch.linalg.svd)

```
u_, s_, vh_ = torch.linalg.svd(x)
is_same = torch.allclose(x, u_ @ torch.diag_embed(s_) @ vh_)
```

They return `True` when nn.DataParallel is not used.
`x` is a tensor of non-negative values of size (22,64,64).

Comment: Are your experiments without `nn.DataParallel` still using CUDA? The SVD implementations which PyTorch uses on CPU and CUDA are different. If everything's on CUDA, then maybe there's just a numerical precision issue. Also, are the two reconstructions all that different? Is it significant for your use case?

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderGuyer. Both of your above suggestions were correct. My experiment withot nn.DataParallel was not using CUDA. It was a numerical precision issue of the CUDA svd implementation. Changing my input tensor to double from float fixed my problem.